# Microservice Architecture - API Gateway or Client-to-Microservice Communication?

Tags: rest, architecture, microservices, backend

I'm designing the architecture for a side project using the Microservices architecture and I'm not sure what the best pattern is for my use case.

My use case is an application where users will interact through the WebUI (Angular) and IoT devices will connect and send data to the backend using MQTT. I do expect the main workload would be IoT devices communicating with the application instead of users accessing it.

I plan to split the application into a few microservices (e.g. IAM, MQTT Broker, Device Management, etc.) but I don't know the best pattern for this use case regarding the integration of the services and how the WebUI will access the services.

I think the following options:

1. Each microservice exposes an RPC interface (e.g. gRPC) and the requests sent by the WebUI would go to an API Gateway, where it exposes the REST API and coordinates requests to the microservices (a.k.a Backend for Frontend).
2. Each microservice exposes a REST API related to its functionality (e.g. IAM exposes /auth/login) and each microservice has all data it needs to process its requests (as result, data can be duplicated in different microservices). The integration between the microservices would be by Kafka.

The first approach seems so much simpler than the second one, but I see a lot of problems, such as the API Gateway would be a single point of failure, increase of latency as the request would go first to the API Gateway and then to the service, and the API Gateway will act almost as a monolithic application. In addition to that, functionality would need implementation in the microservices and the API Gateway. For me, it seems a bad approach.

The second approach seems good as it doesn't have a single point of failure, any feature needs to be implemented only in the microservices and it seems more scalable, but more complex and it would request a reverse proxy (e.g. Nginx) to map the requests (based on the URL) to the correct microservice (e.g. requests to /auth/login would be redirected to the IAM service).

What do you guys think it's the best option? Do you see another approach for this?

Comment: If you don't need gateway, try to avoid it. But sometimes there are justified reasons to use gateway, for example if you use websockets.